# Event layer not editable when using ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, events

I have created a model using ModelBuilder in ArcMap where points are automatically plotted based on coordinates. I have noticed that the layer cannot be edited and if I try I get the following message; "event later not editable".

Comment: It sounds like you're creating an XY event layer, see the help topic that matches your error message https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000034000000 you will need to export your event points to a feature class in order to edit these features.

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to you using ModelBuilder.

As per the Help page on [Warning: Event layer not editable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/event-layer-not-editable.htm):

> Event layers that are based on tables without ObjectID fields cannot
>   be edited in ArcGIS.
>
> **Solution**: Export the event layer to a new feature class or use an editable table for the data source of the event layer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!